# Using PowerShell Resize-Partition on RAID 1 Volume

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, powershell

Can I use the PowerShell command `Resize-Partition` within a RAID 1 volume to move space between two partitions (the size of the volume itself is not changing) without any adverse side effects? If not, is there some other way to do this without wiping the volume out and starting over from scratch?

### Details

I have two Windows 2012R2 servers each with two hard drives in a RAID 1 configuration. The RAID volumes are already using the full disk space available; however, they have two partitions: C for system files and D for shared files. What I would like to do is use the PowerShell command `Resize-Partition` to remove some extra, unneeded space from the C partition and then add it to the D partition. That said, I have been unable to find any specific documentation indicating that I can do this within a RAID 1 volume. It appears that I should be able to; however, since these are production servers and I have no way to test this myself, I am extremely reluctant to try it and risk having to restore the server from a backup.

(As a note, those in charge are unwilling to spend money to add additional storage that would let me move the shared files off of these volumes. So here I am, doing my best to squeeze out as much space as possible.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "Yes and no." In this situation, resizing the partition labeled "C:" is just a matter of issuing the command `Resize-Partition -DriveLetter C -Size (###GB)`. The problem is that the unallocated space this creates is physically ahead of the partition labeled "D:" on the hard disks, and PowerShell will not resize the partition unless the unallocated space is physically after the targeted partition (making the whole command limited in its usefulness).

Adding the unallocated space to the D partition requires using software that would support that procedure or deleting the existing D partition and recreating it with the full amount of unallocated space. For the moment, neither is an option for me, but hopefully this helps someone else out.